# Create input text fields based on value user selects in dropdown in Django forms

Tags: django, python-3.x, dynamic, django-forms

In my application, on page loads by default there is a drop-down with value '3' and three input text fields.

If user selects value '2' from drop-down then number of input text fields should be changed from 3 to 2.

If user selects value '5' from drop-down then number of input text fields should be changed from prev. value to 5.

How could I do that dynamically in Django project as I am wanted to create a form in django inside forms.py?

Comment: Your question is not clear and it's very confusing. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: @Goran I updated my question. Kindly provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few different ways, but in any case you need to control a number of input fields by JavaScript. You didn't show us you model so we can't give you the best solution, but you have a following options:

- if your form is model form, create a form with all possible fields and display/hide fields based on selected value from drop down.
- you can use a [formset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) if your input fields belongs to the same model
- you can add as many fields as you need by JS and process the form fields in view. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19949097/928017) can be used as reference

I hope it helps