# how to read input from arrays in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following form

```
{% for key in keys %}
   <th>
      <div class="card-body">
         <label for="{{ key }}">Should We import this column?</label>
         <input id="{{ key }}" name="import[]" value="{{ key }}" type="checkbox">                             
      </div>
   </th>
{% endfor %}
```

which renders like this

```
<input id="name" name="import[]" value="name" type="checkbox">
<input id="name" name="import[]" value="email" type="checkbox">
<input id="name" name="import[]" value="category" type="checkbox">
```

what I expect is when the checkboxes are selected the value should be present in the `import[]` array. but after the form is posted, what I get is,

```
 # from request.POST array 

'import[]' = 'email' # whichever I selected last
```

where what i expect is the following,

```
import = [
   'email',
   'name'
]
```

how can i achieve this in django, i am not using any forms so far.

`Django 2`, `Python 3.5`

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947538/django-form-with-unknown-number-of-checkbox-fields-and-multiple-actions

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question. Use `request.POST.getlist()`. And drop the `[]` in the names.

Comment: Lovely question mate I thought that this was impossible but apparently is :)