# Get data from one model to another in form of check buttons and then save the checked buttons in different model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a problem that requires to add choices. User will enter the things they Like one by one. I'll use `formset` for that.

My Like model is like this

```
class Likee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

Let's suppose User has entered 10 things here.

What I want to do is to present a form that has `Checkbuttons` against the entries provided by user. These will define all the things that the user `Need`. I want user to select/descelect from all the entries and once he presses Next button, I want to save all the in the DB in a `Need` model.

How can this be achieved? What will the `Need` model,form,view be like? I am out of ideas here.

Comment: this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947538/django-form-with-unknown-number-of-checkbox-fields-and-multiple-actions